# Git - Gitolite - Cloning

Tags: git, gitolite

I have recently set up Gitolite on my serveur. Everything works well.

So I push a new repo on the server, and clone it on another machine to test it. No errors.

I then try to clone it on my server (the same server where Gitolite is installed but different account) and I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, *****@*****.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have tested with another repository, same thing, it works locally but not on the server.

Any idea what could cause this or how to find out? I'm pretty new to all this.

note: I never get any error when using git commands.

Comment: What exact address did you use when cloning your repo on the Gitolite server?

Comment: It actually works now, I just have to set the files and folders permissions correctly.

Comment: Excellent. Could you post below as an answer what exactly you had to do in order to make it work? Others facing the same error message will thank you later ;)

Comment: Yep but this isn't actually solving the problem, well it does but when I clone the repo the files and folders permissions are not right and I don't understand why. Thought it would be because of the umask but it wasn't.

Comment: For the umask, see the link and questions mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109219/gitolite-hooks-do-not-execute/10110771#10110771

Answer (score 0):

> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

You might want to take a look around in the apache logs and see if you can find the actual error message.

Comment: Where can I find this log? I'm on Centos 5. I just did another, with just a single php file echoing HelloWorld, and I get the same error.

Comment: I don't have a file or dir called apache in /var/log

Comment: Might also be `/var/log/httpd`.