# Gitolite hooks do not execute

Tags: git, hook, gitolite

I'm attempting to create a script to chmod the repo files to a new group after a push occurs. To test hooks, I created a hook that creates a file in /tmp/ just to check that the hook is working. It is not however.

What I've done so far:
First I created a script (~/.gitolite/hooks/common/update.secondary), then ran gl-setup [pubkey]. After numerous tries doing this, I checked the main hooks directory (/var/gitolite/hook/common/) and the script was not there.

After that I put the script directly in /var/gitolite/hook/common/, ran gl-setup again, and it still did not run the hook.

The script executes fine as the gitolite user using

```
sh ~/repositories/[some project]/hooks/myscript
```

The script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/TESTFILE
```

The permission update script:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 750 -R /home/git/repositories/*
```

Comment: Did you make it `chmod+x` before running the `gl-setup`?

Comment: I did that using the first method. But not the second...and it works now that I have.

Comment: Excellent. I have published an answer for more visibility

Comment: However, it seems that returning to my original problem, changing the group permissions, does not work. I have updated my original post to include the script. Do the permissions get rewritten after the update.secondary script gets executed?

Comment: Tell me if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915482/gitolite-and-file-permissions/9915919#9915919 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086325/setting-umask-in-git-gitolite/7103499#7103499 help here (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455070/permission-problems-with-git-sharedrepository/5455127#5455127)

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OP Jason Kaczmarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410343/jason-kaczmarsky) mentions that:

- putting the script directly in `/var/gitolite/hook/common/`
- chmod+x said script before
- running gl-setup

works and does propagate that script.

The first alternative mentioned by the OP is described in Gitolite man page "[Using Hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hooks.html)", but it depends on the installation method, which seems to be the [root one here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/root.html).

That being said, regarding `chmod` operation, you need to take into account the [variable `REPO_UMASK` in your `gitolite.rc`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html#gitolite_rc_most_often_used_changed_variables_), as explained in:

- "[gitolite and file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915482/gitolite-and-file-permissions/9915919#9915919)"
- "[Permission problems with Git sharedRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455070/permission-problems-with-git-sharedrepository/5455127#5455127)"
- "[Setting umask in Git / Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086325/setting-umask-in-git-gitolite/7103499#7103499)"